# Compare String to Column in SQL Server, and Return a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure if I should create a View, Stored Procedure, or function for this, but here is what I have so far:

```
USE [HomeStorageQA2]

GO
DECLARE @SearchValue Varchar(255)
DEClare @Flag Varchar(255)
SET @Flag = NULL
SET @SearchValue = 'Inner point(s) > outer point(s);'
Declare @MainString Varchar(255)
Set @MainString = dbo.GetComments
if Charindex(@SearchValue,@MainString) > 0
begin
Set @Flag = 'True'
end
Select  'Flag' = @Flag
go
```

If I `Set @MainString = [Some value containing SearchValue]` , then the query returns `True`.
I want to use this query for the rows in `TestComments.Comments`; so it's comparing the value of `Comments` to the `@SearchValue`, and returning True or False for each row.

I already have a Stored Procedure `dbo.GetComments` to find a match via an identifier called `SummaryID` in the `TestComments` table.

1. My final goal is to be able to create a Select statement with three columns of data: `SummaryID`, `Comments`, and the corresponding `@Flag` value for all rows in `TestComments`. Will this syntax be able to create what I need, and how do I set `@MainString` to the value I want?
2. Should this be created as a stored procedure, function, or view?
   (I'm assuming Stored Procedure or Function)

Comment: Anything but stored proc

Comment: Funny enough, my predecessors already created tons of Stored Procedures and Functions, and very few views.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a stored procedure version:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindMatches
    @searchValue varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT SummaryID
    , Comments
    , CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@searchValue, Comments) > 0 THEN 'True'
        ELSE 'False'
        END AS Flag
FROM TestComments
END
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Sorry. I was in a rush when I wrote my original answer. Fixed and tested on my own rig. It should work for you now. :)

Answer (score 2):

make it a proc/fnc if and only if it rises to the level of re-usability and coveted status that it belongs there. if you don't know the difference, then the answer is no. it is probably random gibberish not worthy of such status, less you desire a system of way crazy inching toward an inevitable [face-palm](http://tinyurl.com/nrjcoz3)

Comment: Thanks for the reality check; reuseability is definitely something to keep in mind. Thankfully, with Mark's answer we can use this to search for other comment flags.

Answer (score 1):

For example you can create a scalar function that returns bit. The it is done like:

```
select SummaryID, Comments, dbo.FunctionName(Comments, @searchString)  
from TestComments
```